# Extra empty lines when pasting text from IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I have a very simple html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
   <title></title>
</head>
<body>
   <div>This is line 1</div>
   <div>This is line 2</div>
   <div>This is line 3</div>
</body>
```

If I open this page in IE 11 (or CHtmlView) and try to select all and copy into clipboard and then paste in notepad I will get extra empty line after each line.

[image]

This will not happen if I do the same with Chrome.  Any idea why is this happening?  Is there a way around it?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using `*{margin:0, border:0};`

Comment: Note: Your first line declares HTML. Your second line tries to put this in the XHTML namespace. I'm sure you're not using XHTML so remove the xmlns part. And the `<meta>` tag does not use or need the closing slash.